# Comparing two sets of data in a memory efficient way

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a podcast app. Some podcasts have hundreds of episodes and all of these are saved in core data.

I would like to refresh the app's data on launch which means I need to parse all the feeds and I end up with a list of episodes parsed from the internet and a list of episodes saved in core data. I would like to compare both sets of data in order to add new episodes to core data. What is the best memory efficient way of doing it?

I was just thinking of using a `for in` loop.

Thank you

Comment: The "Core Data Programming Guide" (you *did* read it, didn't you :) has a chapter "Efficiently Importing Data" with  sections "Reducing Peak Memory Footprint" and "Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently", that could be a good place to start ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for in loop shouldn't be too bad for collecting the things you want to compare from the server. Usually this is the fastest way to iterate. After you get your comparators however, the next step is a little different since core data is a special breed. You almost definitely don't want to just grab everything out of core data and fast iterate again to compare. You might want to look into using a fetchRequest and including a predicate to check against the data that came back from the server. Find some property of the podcasts that won't be expensive to compare with your fetch request. A string or number ID that is stored in core data and on the server would work pretty well. If the release dates are unique that would work fine as well. Obviously don't try comparing something crazy expensive like the audio data and make sure it's unique.